# How to append key value pair into HTTPHeaders

Tags: ios, swift3, http-headers

I am creating `HTTPHeader` for `Alamofire` request in this way.

```
 var headerToken:HTTPHeaders!
    if(isAuthorized)
    {
        let token="Bearer "+dm.strAuthToken
        headerToken=[
            "Authorization":token,
             "Accept":"application/json"
        ]
```

}

And now I want to add another header field into this same header object. My new key value pair should be like

```
"FormData":dm.strFormData
```

how can I append this into the same `headertoken` object

Thank you so much

**UPDATE**

That new key value pair should be added only if it satisfies `if(dm.isWorkflowAdded)`

Answer (score 0):

Just add headerToken["FormData"] = dm.strFormData

Answer (score 0):

Add this after your current code.

```
    if(dm.isWorkflowAdded)
    {
        headerToken["FormData"] = dm.strFormData
    }
```